# How to "BeginScope" for a specific Custom Scoped lifestyle in Castle Windsor?

Tags: scope, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, using-statement, castle-windsor-3

I've created a [custom Scope Accessor](http://docs.castleproject.org/(S(kwaa14uzdj55gv55dzgf0vui))/Windsor.Implementing%20custom%20scope.ashx) (it simply returns the DefaultLifetimeScope) to be able to add a custom scoped lifestyle. The component is then registered as

```
Component
   .For<..>
   .LifestyleScoped<CustomScope>()
```

However, I am at a loss as how to actually *start* a new CustomScope scope/lifetime. [The documentation shows](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.LifeStyles.ashx) starting a new scope using

```
using (Container.BeginScope()) {
   // ..
}
```

but my goal is to create/begin/start a *specific* scope, not that for a generic `LifestyleScoped()` registration. The new scope should only affect components explicitly registered to CustomScope; not generic scoped components or components registered against other scoped lifestyles.

*What is the process to begin a (My Custom Scope) scope / lifetime?*

Please link to the relevant documentation; as I'm asking because I was not able to find it readily. The code is using Castle Windsor 3.3.

---

Background:

I am coming from Autofac and am looking for the equivalent of an [Instance Per Matching Lifetime Scope](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-matching-lifetime-scope) to establish a UoW over an EF context. There may be multiple UoWs "per request" and there might be different UoWs for different repositories - I would also like the support for nesting in the future.

While there are numerous articles talking about creating a UoW pattern, they are [all] tied (incorrectly, IMOHO) to some context such as HTTP or WFC request - and that is not what this question is about. I am specifically interested in how to start a custom scope that flows down through the call graph and "lives inside" the using block.

---

Notes:

The `BoundTo()` (and `LifestyleBoundTo()`/`LifestyleBoundToNearest()`) lifestyles work against the object-graph (and requires altering the types) and switching to such is not strictly a solution/answer to this question. However, if a good case can be made for them ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Container.BeginScope()` initializes a new `CallContextLifeTimeScope`.

https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/aa9b8b353ee2e533d586495eec254e216f800c09/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Lifestyle/LifestyleExtensions.cs

```
using Scope = Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.Scoped.CallContextLifetimeScope;

public static class LifestyleExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable BeginScope(this IKernel kernel)
    {
        return new Scope(kernel);
    }
    /* rest of the code removed for simplicity */
}
```

This extension method doesn't care about your custom `ILifetimeScope` implementation.

Instead of calling `Container.BeginScope()`, you can just `new CustomScope()` and dispose it in the end to make sure your "custom scoped objects" released properly.

You can call `Container.BeginScope()` inside your `CustomScope` and dispose them both in the end in order to support components registered with default lifetime scope.